# App not deploying on BlackBerry Simulator 4.2 with Eclipse 3.7

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am developing a BlackBerry application with Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) and the BlackBerry Eclipse plugin.  My application is not deploying on the BlackBerry Simulator 4.2.0.46.
If I close and clear the simulator and run the project, it is working but after all not deploying the app on the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlackBerry OS 4.2 is very old.  You really do not need to target OS 4.2.  It is quite rare. Look at 4.5 or 4.6 as a minimum these days.  WhatsApp, one of the most popular third party apps for BlackBerry, does not support anything earlier than OS 4.6.

In your question, you say "If I close and clear the simulator and run the project, it is working but after all not deploying the app on the simulator."  When you say 'it is working' what do you mean?  It seems it isn't working, as you want to deploy your app, so the wording there is confusing.

Comment: here working means deploying. When i close and clear the simulator and the run it deploying and if again run it while the simulator is present its not deploying the last Build is present in the simulator not changed as i modified.
Solution I Found : if i change the eclipse workspace and import the working it deploying everytime when i run the project.